# CKShare - Failed to modify some records error - CloudKit

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckshare

I'm trying to share a record with other users in `CloudKit` but I keep getting an error. When I tap one of the items/records on the table I'm presented with the `UICloudSharingController` and I can see the `iMessage` app icon, but when I tap on it I get an error and the `UICloudSharingController` disappears, the funny thing is that even after the error I can still continue using the app.

Here is what I have.

### Code

```
var items = [CKRecord]()
var itemName: String?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = items[indexPath.row]

    let share = CKShare(rootRecord: item)

    if let itemName = item.object(forKey: "name") as? String {
        self.itemName = item.object(forKey: "name") as? String
        share[CKShareTitleKey] = "Sharing \(itemName)" as CKRecordValue?
    } else {
        share[CKShareTitleKey] = "" as CKRecordValue?
        self.itemName = "item"
    }
    share[CKShareTypeKey] = "bundle.Identifier.Here" as CKRecordValue
    prepareToShare(share: share, record: item)
}


private func prepareToShare(share: CKShare, record: CKRecord){

    let sharingViewController = UICloudSharingController(preparationHandler: {(UICloudSharingController, handler: @escaping (CKShare?, CKContainer?, Error?) -> Void) in

        let modRecordsList = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [record, share], recordIDsToDelete: nil)

        modRecordsList.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = {
            (record, recordID, error) in

            handler(share, CKContainer.default(), error)
        }
        CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.add(modRecordsList)
    })

    sharingViewController.delegate = self

    sharingViewController.availablePermissions = [.allowPrivate]
    self.navigationController?.present(sharingViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}



// Delegate Methods:
func cloudSharingControllerDidSaveShare(_ csc: UICloudSharingController) {
    print("saved successfully")
}
func cloudSharingController(_ csc: UICloudSharingController, failedToSaveShareWithError error: Error) {
    print("failed to save: \(error.localizedDescription)")// the error is generated in this method
}
func itemThumbnailData(for csc: UICloudSharingController) -> Data? {
    return nil //You can set a hero image in your share sheet. Nil uses the default.
}
func itemTitle(for csc: UICloudSharingController) -> String? {
    return self.itemName
}
```

### ERROR

> Failed to modify some records

### Here is what I see...

[image]

Any idea what could be wrong?

### EDIT:

By the way, the error is generated in the `cloudSharingController failedToSaveShareWithError` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to share in the default zone which isn't allowed. From the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord/1640378-share)

> Sharing is only supported in zones with the
>   CKRecordZoneCapabilitySharing capability. The default zone does not
>   support sharing.

So you should set up a custom zone in your private database, and save your share and records there.

Comment: Ok, it starting to make sense. If I'm understanding this correctly if you are going to share your `CKRecords` they need to be saved in the `PrivateDatabase` under a custom `Zone` and the same goes for the `CKShare`. Now, is there anything special about the custom zone? In other words, are there any special settings that need to be turned on in the `CloudKit Dashboard`

Comment: Nothing special.  I'd highly recommend watching the WWDC videos about CloudKit, specifically the 2016 CloudKit Best Practices one: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/231/.  And skim through the quick start guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987

Comment: Creating the custom zone and using that instead of the _defaultZone, resolved the error. Thanks.

Comment: @ Brian M.  Could you please clarify the following: I started to save every single record in the app in the `CustomZone` and now I can share records with other users, the issue now is that when I test the app in a second device and try to create new records, that device does not have access to the `CustomZone`. Am I supposed use in the `_defaultZone` as the main zone for all users and only save the items that need to be shared in the `CustomZone`? Is that the process?

Comment: To clarify/answer my question above, I was under the impression that once you create a custom zone using the `CloudKit Dashboard` it would be available in all devices using the app; wrong assumption. It appears that any custom zone will need to be created in code for each user. Custom zones created using the `CloudKit Dashboard` are only visible in the testing device, at least is how I understand it.

Comment: @fs_tigre  - I would recommend watching those WWDC videos and/or going over the quick start guide to get a general overview of how CloudKit operates.  The public database is available for everyone using your app, and each user has a private database.  Within that private database you create custom zones and you can share records from those custom zones.  Any custom zone you create in a private zone will be available to that user on any device they are logged in on.  If you create a custom zone in dashboard, it's in the private database of that Apple ID, and only visible to that account.

Comment: I have watched all videos; they are very helpful, but for some reason I thought that zones needed to be created in the dashboard like the db schema, but it now make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it is from the way you're trying to instantiate the UICloudSharingController?  I cribbed my directly from the docs and it works:

```
let cloudSharingController = UICloudSharingController { [weak self] (controller, completion: @escaping (CKShare?, CKContainer?, Error?) -> Void) in
    guard let `self` = self else {
       return
    }
    self.share(rootRecord: rootRecord, completion: completion)
}
```

If that's not the problem it's something with either one or both of the records themselves. If you upload the record without trying to share it, does it work?

EDIT TO ADD:

What is the CKShareTypeKey? I don't use that in my app.  Also I set my system fields differently:

```
share?[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = "Something"
```

Comment: Would you mind showing the code that is working for you, I'm honestly lost. The code came from the following tutorial... https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-shopping-list-application-with-cloudkit-sharing-shopping-items--cms-31409

Comment: @ Brian M - I tried using the code snippet from the Apple documentation but I got two errors. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicloudsharingcontroller **1-** *Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x...; recordName=Share-..., zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__> to server: Shares cannot exist in the default zone* **2-** *Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x...; recordName=53745..., zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__> to server: Can't share records in the default zone*.  **Any idea what could be?**

Comment: That's it right there - you can't share anything from your private database unless it is in a custom zone.  Default zone doesn't allow sharing.

Comment: @ Brian M Right now I don't have any custom zones, the records are saved directly in the `_defaultZone`. Do you think I need to be saving the records in my `Private Database` in a custom zone?

Comment: Yes that's your problem.  I've put a link to the docs in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your info.plist

```
<key>CKSharingSupported</key>
<true/>
```